# Handling empty nodes in XML via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have this code to parse XML. How would I address an empty node in the XML? At present no output is delivered at all with the "v2" node being empty...

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "sample.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>c1</th><th>c2</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("v1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("v2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

XML:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <v1>some data</v1>
        <v2/>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: You say "At present no output is delivered at all with the "v2" node being empty" but what exactly is the problem? Do you expect something to come back? Is there an error you forgot to mention?

Comment: @AndrewLohr There's no error. Simply nothing loads at all. I would like the empty node to simply return empty value in the table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if it is not empty then use the data otherwise just skip it.

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", `data:text/xml,<products>
    <product>
        <v1>some data</v1>
        <v2/>
    </product>
</products>`, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>c1</th><th>c2</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("v1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>";
    var v2c = x[i].getElementsByTagName("v2")[0].childNodes;
    if (v2c.length > 0){
      table += v2c[0].nodeValue;
    }
    table += "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="loadDoc()">Load</button>
<table id="demo" border="1"></table>
```

Comment: Maybe I needed to check for the length of the childNodes property, my first assumption was that it would be undefined for an empty node

Comment: ...I retracted my reply, regarding the fix... still having an issue with nothing loading

Comment: I worked out this on my end (below) and it works but yours as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

own revision:

```
if (v2c.length > 0){
   table += v2c[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>";
} else {
   table += "</td><td>";
}
```